# Keep jQuery out of global namespace

Tags: jquery

Am working on a script that requires jQuery. It will be loaded on a website which may or may not already have jQuery loaded.  Is there some way that I can have my version of jQuery loaded outside the global namespace so that it won't be accessible outside of my anonymous function?

Comment: are you worried about collision or do you just not want to load it if it's already there?

Comment: Would it be possible to initialize jQuery only within your anonymous function?

Comment: If you [look at the source](http://robflaherty.github.io/jquery-annotated-source/docs/01-core.html), `$` and `jQuery` are both added to the `window`, making them global. You might be able to save the original jQuery to a different variable and then restore it when you are done with yours but that seems scary...

Comment: You want to have the $ variable accessible only in `jQuery(document).ready(function() { });` right ?

Comment: Honestly, you should just make it a requirement for your library that requires jQuery... jQuery has very good support for backwards compatibility, so unless your script is doing some really crazy stuff you should be able to require that the client has jQuery 1.6+ already on the page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need, just properly use noConflict. That is its intended purpose.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="someplugin.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        $.doSomething();
    })($.noConflict(true));
</script>
```

Though depending on the situation, it's usually better to just require the client to have jquery included before including your code. *(Polaris878 hinted at this in a comment to your question)*

Comment: It completely removes jQuery from the global namespace, reverting it back to what it was before he included his version of jQuery while leaving it accessible only within his anonymous function. Is that not what he wants?

Comment: Should you not pass `jQuery.noConflict(true)` to the function? Or I guess that would only be if you're concerned about conflicting with `$` in another library.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Either will work, since the script is executing immediately after jquery.js and some plugin, we can be sure that both `$` and `jQuery` reference the same thing unless someplugin.js overrides it.

Comment: Ohh, now I see that he and you meant. withdraw my last comment. +1.

Comment: I was worried that noConflict would remove jQuery's $ entire from the global namespace, which could be a problem for the client if they were using jQuery previously. But, what I'll do is first check if jQuery is loaded, if it is then I use it, if not I will load it in and set it to noConflict.

Comment: It will only remove the most recently added instance of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should check if jQuery is already loaded. If it is loaded, you simply make use of it otherwise load jQuery and make use of it. A simple javascript can make it possible

```
myjQ = null;

if (typeof window.jQuery == 'undefined') {
  load_script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js', callback_fn );
} else {
  callback_fn();
}

load_script = function(url, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  if (script.readyState) {
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (script.readyState == "loaded" || script.readyState == "complete") {
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
        callback();
      }
    };
  } else {
    script.onload = function () {
      callback();
    };
  }

  script.src = url;
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
};

callback_fn = function(){
  myjQ = jQuery.noConflict();

  // you can use myjQ just like $ here. 
}
```

may be you can wrap all these functions in an object so that they will not pollute global namespace.